# Bash : value too great for base

Tags: bash

I am having issues with substitution of variable name. This is my program

```
DEV1="d21f5600-0cd0-11e8-03e9461109ca"
echo $1
echo $2
if [[ $1 == "DEV1"  || $1 == "DEV2"  || $1 == "DEV3" ]] 
then
     echo "Correct ID"
     echo $1
     echo  "'$(($1))'"
else
     echo "Wrong ID"
fi
```

When i run the program like this

```
bash test.sh DEV1
```

This is the output i am getting

```
DEV1

Correct ID
DEV1
test.sh: line 8: d21f5600-0cd0: value too great for base (error token is "0cd0")
```

What is the issue with printing the whole string content of DEV1 as it is

Comment: What do you think `$((` `))` is doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(( ))` evaluates its contents as an arithmetic expression. It looks to me like you're trying to use it to get the contents of the variable named by `$1`, but to treat that as a simple string rather than as an arithmetic expression. To do that, you can use indirect expansion with `${!indirectvar}`:

```
#!/bin/bash
DEV1="d21f5600-0cd0-11e8-03e9461109ca"
echo $1
echo $2
if [[ $1 == "DEV1"  || $1 == "DEV2"  || $1 == "DEV3" ]]
then
     echo "Correct ID"
     echo $1
     echo  "'${!1}'"    # Indirect expansion here
else
     echo "Wrong ID"
fi
```

Note that I also added a shebang line to indicate that it's a bash script (not plain sh, perl, etc). This and adding execute permission (`chmod +x test.sh`) lets you run it properly with `./filename`:

```
$ ./test.sh DEV1
DEV1

Correct ID
DEV1
'd21f5600-0cd0-11e8-03e9461109ca'
```

BTW, there are a couple of other things I'd recommend changing: all-caps variable names are a bit dicey, since there are a number of all-caps environment variables that have special meanings, and if you accidentally use one it can have weird effects. Therefore, lower- or mixed-case variables are safer. Also, using file extensions (like .sh) with scripts isn't generally recommended, since the shebang line is the better way to indicate what language it's written. But `test` is an important builtin command that you don't ever want to override, so I'd recommend using a less generic name for the script.

Answer (score 1):

Minimal example to reproduce the error is

```
DEV1="d21f5600-0cd0-11e8-03e9461109ca"
echo  "'$(($DEV1))'"
```

$((...)) is bashs arithmetic evaluation.

```
echo $((d21f5600-1690-1118-43e9461109ca))
```

leads to the very same error.

To evaluate hexadecimal values arithmetically - I guess that's not what you try to do - you have to prefix them with 0x:

```
echo $((0xd21f5600-0x0cd0-0x11e8-0x03e9461109ca))
-4296912523906
```